# cbind factor vector with level names

Tags: r

I create three vectors and try to combine them into one table using cbind.  The third vector is a factor with three levels.  I get this output:

```
 v1 <- c(1,2,3)
 v2 <- c(4,5,6)
 v3 <- factor(c('lorem','ipsum','dolor'))
 cbind(v1,v2,v3)
     v1 v2 v3
[1,]  1  4  3
[2,]  2  5  2
[3,]  3  6  1
```

Preferred output would be:

```
 cbind(v1,v2,v3)
     v1 v2 v3
[1,]  1  4  lorem
[2,]  2  5  ipsum
[3,]  3  6  dolor
```

Is it possible to get the level names instead of the ID to display as above?

Comment: I think you need `data.frame` instead of `cbind` as `cbind` gives a matrix and `matrix` can hold only a single class. The factor gets coerced to numeric values

Comment: Try `cbind(v1, v2, v3=levels(v3)[v3])` if you need to use `cbind`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about why you need to do this way.  It is better to use `data.frame` which can hold multiple classes.  By using `cbind`, we get a `matrix` and a `matrix` can hold only a single class.  So, even if there is a single non-numeric value, the columns are all transformed to 'character' class.

```
 cbind(v1, v2, v3=levels(v3)[v3])
 #     v1  v2  v3     
 #[1,] "1" "4" "lorem"
 #[2,] "2" "5" "ipsum"
 #[3,] "3" "6" "dolor"
```

Or

```
 cbind(v1, v2, v3=as.character(v3))
```

Comment: Thanks.  Didn't think about data.frame; though it might have been obvious.